# Running an executable with fixed execution-time and memory limit and getting exit-code

Tags: command-line, executable, memory-usage, resource-limiting

What is the best way to run an executable with execution-time  and memory(RAM) limit (e.g. 2.5 seconds and 32768 kB)?

I need to get the exit-code if it exits without violating time and memory limits. Otherwise it should be killed and I need to know which limit it violated (e.g. `MEMORY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED`, `TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend this nice tool, it'll limit CPU time or memory consumption:

https://github.com/pshved/timeout

Comment: Will it work on windows too if I install Perl?

Comment: No it won't, after looking at the code it uses pure unix/posix calls.

Comment: Is there anything like this but that will work for both Linux and Windows? I want to write an [OJ][1] which will work both for Windows and Linux. 
  [1]: http://http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_judge

Comment: Sure I will. :)

Comment: Is it possible to disallow child processes?